# How to find the derivative of a function that depends on it's previous states?

Tags: derivatives, numerical-methods, partial-derivative

This is the equation where n denotes the current state, (n-1) denotes the state in the previous step etc.

[image]

And to do back-propagation I need to find partial derivatives over each of the variables. For now let's just focus on [image]

The term [image] in the above equation can be written as:

[image]

Since it also contains [image], it needs to be substituted into the first equation. But this is where the issue starts. I also need to then substitute [image] in the equation above with this:

[image]

Where the term [image] contains [image]. And I end up in a never ending loop.

So how to do this?